# Distributing iOS app as a B2B custom app and also making it available in the general app store

Tags: ios, app-store, b2b, app-distribution

I have a requirement from a client who would like to distribute my app available in the App Store via. Apple Business Program to their employees. Of course, there will be some client-specific customizations added to the app but those will not take effect in a non-MDM environment. So it should be safe enough to distribute the app in the general app store. However, I would like to understand the possibilities of distributing an app (without having to maintain 2 different code base] through general App Store AND as a custom B2B app.

I have been going through some documentation from Apple about signing the paid app agreement.

[Paid App Agreement Info](https://help.apple.com/app-store-connect/#/deva001f4a14)

[Custom Apps](https://developer.apple.com/business/custom-apps/)

It says:

> Once this contract is requested, you can’t undo this action or revert to the Developer Program License Agreement for free apps

Does this mean that once I sign the agreement, I can't update my free app in the general store?

Other Questions:

1. Can there be free apps and custom apps submitted under the same iTunes Connect account?
2. Is code signing requirement different for a custom B2B app than app store app. Ex: different kind of distribution certificate?
3. If code-signing requirement is not different, can the same binary (same bundle id/version number) be uploaded under different iTunes Connect account – one as a free app and the other as a custom app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The section you have quoted refers to the *legal agreement* you have signed. Once you have signed the Paid App agreement, you can't "unsign" it and revert to the Free App agreement.

It does not refer to the types of apps you can distribute. You can distribute both free and paid apps under the Paid App agreement.

In answer to your other questions:

1. Yes
2. No, custom apps are signed for App Store distribution, are still uploaded to App Store Connect and are still reviewed by Apple
3. No. In App Store Connect you will have two apps (one custom, one free) so they will have different Bundle IDs at least, even if all other code is identical.  You will need to upload different builds.

If your custom app is absolutely identical to the one you are proposing to offer as a custom app, then you may not even need a custom app; the company can use Apple Business Manager and their MDM to obtain your free app and push it to their users. You do, however, need to consider what would happen if some other organisation distributed your app via an MDM; would your customisation "activate" and would that cause a problem?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The customization depends on app configurations set up in the MDM unless an org can provide the same config keys and valid values,  they can't avail the customizations. Can you please explain this  "the company can use Apple Business Manager and their MDM to obtain your free app and push it to their users". Is this the same as linking a public app in to MDM tool and then it shows up in their app catalog?

Comment: Yes, exactly.  A B2B app can only be "purchased" by the Apple IDs you list, but Apple Business Manager users can purchase any publicly available app that is on the store.